# How to do Pattern Matching in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have no idea if there exists a pattern matching function for Common Lisp, nevertheless I have to make my own function. I have no idea about Lisp. Can somebody give heads-up on learning Lisp and most importantly, how to go about doing pattern matching in Lisp. I will have to pass a pattern and a fact and say if they match.
An example would be

```
(heroes (hitpoints=hp) (mana=m))
```

should match

```
(Morphling (hitpoints 435) (mana 260))
```

it should also be able to also do numeric comparisons of if a number is greater or lesser. Like if another heroes mana is less that Morphling.

Comment: Excellent description in Paul Graham's [On Lisp](http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.pdf) (Chapter 19, p246ff)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple pattern matching functionality is explained in various Lisp books.

- [Lisp, 3rd edition, Winston/Horn](http://people.csail.mit.edu/phw/Books/#Lisp)
- [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming, Case Studies in Common Lisp, Peter Norvig](http://norvig.com/paip.html)

and others.

Above books explain implementing pattern matching in Lisp very well.

Libraries exist, for example [trivia](https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia/), [cl-match](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-match/doc/clmatch.htm), and [various others](http://www.cliki.net/pattern%20matching).

Comment: I cannot use library functions.I have to make my own.

Comment: @gizgok: a good start would be learning Lisp using the Winston/Horn book. Bonus: it explains implementing pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may want the CL-Unification library: http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-unification/

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to short circuit any learning you need to do for school (if that is the context in which this project is necessitated), but you could study the cl-ppcre library, http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/, to see how an experienced Lisper does it. You could download the source and study it to understand. I would also second the book by Norvig, http://norvig.com/paip.html, mentioned above. You can learn so much from that book.