# Common Lisp dispatch on first element of sequence

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to define methods that dispatch on particular elements (such as the first) in a sequence? Is it possible to do this without using "fully general" predicate dispatch machinery?

I have a program below that rewrites an expression in propositional calculus in negative normal form (i.e. all negation appears before a variable). It also removes all connectives besides `and` and `or` and replaces them with equivalent definitions.

It heavily uses methods, but I don't think I'm using the object system to full effect.

I want to be able to have a bunch of separate `defmethod` cases for `normalize` and `normalize-not` based on the symbol `'and, 'or, 'not, 'imp, 'iff` currently heading the expression.

In particular, I'd like to be able to write something similar to the following

```
(defmethod normalize-all ((exprs ('and list)))
    `(and ,@normalize-all (cdr exprs)))
```

as a standalone definition governing what happens when `exprs` is a list with `'and` as its `car`.

What I have now performs "top-level" type checks only and uses `cond` heavily in the body of functions.

```
(defmethod normalize-all ((exprs list))
  (loop for x in exprs collecting (normalize x)))


(defmethod prepend-not-to-all ((exprs list))
  (loop for x in exprs collecting (list 'not x)))


(defmethod normalize ((expr symbol))
  expr)


(defmethod normalize-not ((expr symbol))
  `(not ,expr))

(defmethod normalize ((expr cons))
  (let
      ((head (car expr))
       (tail (cdr expr)))
    (cond
     ((eq head 'and)
      `(and ,@(normalize-all tail)))
     ((eq head 'or)
      `(or ,@(normalize-all tail)))
     ((eq head 'imp)
      `(or
    ,(normalize `(not ,(first tail)))
    ,(normalize (second tail))))
     ((eq head 'iff)
      `(and ,(normalize `(imp ,(first tail) ,(second tail)))
        ,(normalize `(imp ,(second tail) ,(first tail)))))
     ((eq head 'not)
      (normalize-not (first tail))))))


(defmethod normalize-not ((expr cons))
  (let
      ((head (car expr))
       (tail (cdr expr)))
    (cond
     ((eq head 'and)
      `(or ,@(normalize-all (prepend-not-to-all tail))))
     ((eq head 'or)
      `(and ,@(normalize-all (prepend-not-to-all tail))))
     ((eq head 'imp)
      `(and
    ,(normalize (first tail))
    ,(normalize-not (second tail))))
     ((eq head 'iff)
      `(or
    (normalize-not `(imp ,(first tail) ,(second tail)))
    (normalize-not `(imp ,(second tail) ,(first tail)))))
     ((eq head 'not)
      (normalize (first tail))))))


(print (normalize '(iff a b)))
```

More generally, I'm trying to mimic one style of writing functions in Haskell that looks like the following, because the cases are easy to inspect.

```
f :: Int -> String -> Int
f 0 _ = ...
f 1 (x:xs) = ...
f n _ | n `mod` 2 == 0 = ...
      |      otherwise = ...
```

The pattern appearing before the pipe is based on the structure of the types involved. Ints have no structure (`n+k` patterns don't count are gone anyway), so we can only match on particular integers, ignore the integer with `_` or capture it with a variable.

Arbitrary boolean-valued expressions can appear after the `|` and control whether the definition on the rhs is in effect or not. (`` n `mod` 2 == 0 `` checks whether a number is even, `otherwise` is just `True` but reads better).

Cases that are textually earlier always have precedence over ones that are textually later. And `f` is closed in the sense that all components of its definition must appear at the definition site.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798617/how-to-do-pattern-matching-in-common-lisp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not built in way to do this. If you want to mimic the Haskell style, you could use a pattern matching library such as [Trivia](https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia). It doesn't allow you to write the clauses in separate top-level forms though.

```
;; Dependencies: (ql:quickload '(:fare-quasiquote :trivia :trivia.quasiquote))

(defpackage #:normalize
  (:use #:cl #:named-readtables #:trivia)
  (:export #:normalize #:imp #:iff))
(in-package #:normalize)
(in-readtable :fare-quasiquote)

(defun normalize-all (exprs)
  (mapcar #'normalize exprs))

(defun prepend-not-to-all (exprs)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) `(not ,x)) exprs))

(defun-ematch normalize (expr)
  ;; The body of DEFUN-EMATCH is a list of clauses starting with the
  ;; pattern and followed by a body of forms to execute when the
  ;; pattern matches the sole argument (formatted here for the sake of
  ;; readability with the pattern on the left and the body on the
  ;; right). The EMATCH variant signals an error if no pattern matches
  ;; the input.
  ((type symbol)   expr)
  (`(and ,@tail)   `(and ,@(normalize-all tail)))
  (`(or ,@tail)    `(or ,@(normalize-all tail)))
  (`(imp ,a ,b)    `(or ,(normalize `(not ,a))
                        ,(normalize b)))
  (`(iff ,a ,b)    `(and ,(normalize `(imp ,a ,b))
                         ,(normalize `(imp ,b ,a))))
  (`(not ,expr)    (normalize-not expr)))

(defun-ematch normalize-not (expr)
  ((type symbol)   `(not ,expr))
  (`(and ,@tail)   `(or ,@(normalize-all (prepend-not-to-all tail))))
  (`(or ,@tail)    `(and ,@(normalize-all (prepend-not-to-all tail))))
  (`(imp ,a ,b)    `(and ,(normalize a)
                         ,(normalize-not b)))
  (`(iff ,a ,b)    `(or ,(normalize-not `(imp ,a ,b))
                        ,(normalize-not `(imp ,b ,a))))
  (`(not ,expr)    (normalize expr)))

(normalize '(iff foo bar))
;=> (AND (OR (NOT FOO) BAR) (OR (NOT BAR) FOO))
```

Alternatively, you could have another generic function to handle lists. Something like

```
(defmethod normalize ((expression list))
  (normalize-list (first expression)
                  (rest expression)))

(defmethod normalize-list ((operator (eql 'and)) arguments)
  `(and ,@(normalize-all arguments)))

(defmethod normalize-list ((operator (eql 'or)) arguments)
  `(or ,@(normalize-all arguments)))

;; ...
```

But that's going to get way more verbose than pattern matching.